# java send remainder to system connected in same LAN

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, networking

I have a set of IP address connected via same LAN.

I want to write a java program to send remainder to the other system(Using IP address) connected via same LAN.
Remainder should be either dialog or any kind of format and also the user should able to reply the answer for that remainder.

Please help me to resolve the error.
I'm a amateur java programmer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your response.Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow as well as java.I just started with the help of google but really i do not know how to do that that's why i had posted aforementioned question in stackoverflow.Please provide me a hint i will try to resolve the task.

Answer (score 1):

One possible thing which you can do certainly is use `Java RMI`---Remote Method Invocation to achieve this task. You can communicate with a remote object residing on the computer in the same LAN.

You prepare a code kinda Client-Server program. Treat yourself as a Server and your neighbouring system as a Client! Then you can establish a connection to it using `Java RMI`. One thing which you must make certain is that the other system must have `JDK` installed in it! Then whatever you wanna do, you can do it easily!!!

Some references to Java RMI is :-

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html

http://yama-linux.cc.kagoshima-u.ac.jp/~yamanoue/researches/java/rmi-ex2/

Comment: thank you for your response.But in my situation remote system doesn't have JDK installed,So is there any other solution to resolve this task.

Comment: What kind of system do you have on the other side,means which OS? You can try establishing ssh connection and then creating a process on the same by opening a dialog box in that system using batch(if Windows) or shell(Unix,Linux) scripts! Also, you don't need java specifically for that. Maybe, I am myself not clear much,but,it's indeed a good question!

Comment: Currently it's a windows7 OS.But usually our program should be OS independent.Could you guide me for windows??

Comment: You are stating two different things---firstly,you don't have java on other system and secondly, the code must be OS independent. Can you name me other code which is platform independent other than Java(though there are some,but they are less popular as compared to java). Go through my answer once again, it contains everything what you want only with the exception that you must have java installed on the other system! Also, I have performed this thing on my LAN connection using Java RMI! Please follow that instead of searching other options,it's a good technology to learn though...

Comment: I have successfully implemented RMI also I am able to receive the data in client machine.Now I need to implement event listener for RMI because everytime i need to run the client program to receive the data which is being sent from otherside.I want my client program to run automatically once data is available in server side.This can avoid data loss. Please suggest if you have other possible ways.

Comment: First It's unclear what you want to convey! Second, this is a separate question really. Please post it as a new question and you'll surely get a reply. If not,then lastly,I am here!